# How do I pipe the output of a tool to curl -X POST?

Tags: curl, sensors, iot, pipeline

I want to constantly send the outputs of the program `./airsensor -v` to Ubidots platform using their `curl -X POST` command on my Raspberry Pi.

---

Sending `entropy_avail` number works.

Everytime I issue the following command, I get feedback in terminal and the values appear in Ubidots:

`cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail | curl -X POST --data-urlencode value@- https://things.ubidots.com/api/v1.6/variables/[VARIABLE-ID]/values/?token=[TOKEN-ID]`

---

### Airsensor constantly (every ~ 15sec.) outputs a number:

```
./airsensor -v
450
453
452
457
```

---

... now if I use the following command, it won't work. As it gives no feedback at the terminal at all. And also no values recieved at Ubidots.

`./airsensor -v | curl -X POST --data-urlencode value@- https://things.ubidots.com/api/v1.6/variables/[VARIABLE-ID]/values/?token=[TOKEN-ID]`

---

Resources:

https://ubidots.com/docs/#send-one-value-to-ubidots

https://github.com/tuxedo0801/usb-sensors-linux/blob/master/airsensor/airsensor.c

https://github.com/tuxedo0801/usb-sensors-linux

Answer (score 1):

Using `-d @-` makes curl read from standar input, you can test using this:

```
echo "test $(date)" | curl -X POST -d @- http://httpbin.org/post
```

Or try to combine `stderr` & `stdout` probably your app is only writing to `stderr`

```
./your-app 2>&1 | curl -X POST -d @- http://httpbin.org/post
```

Notice the `2>&1` that will redirect stderr to stdout

Comment: It didn't worked. I was given this command by Ubidots forum:  A=$(echo -e '10') && curl -X POST -d "value=$A" "http://things.ubidots.com/api/v1.6/variables/[VAR-ID]/values?token=[TOKEN]" .... If I try  A=$(echo -e ./airsensor -v) && curl -X POST -d "value=$A" "http://things.ubidots.com/api/v1.6/variables/[VAR-ID]/values?token=[TOKEN]" ... doesnt work and shows: {"value": ["A valid number is required."]}.  || How can I send the output of ./airsensor -v instead of the static number 10 ?

Comment: `curl` is working as expected problem seems to be the endpoint, test using httpbin.org as in the answer to just see what you are sending

Comment: But How to reuse single tcp connection and pipe multiple data one by one to the same url. This example doesn't work  `for i in {0..9};do echo "post_data_$i" done | curl -d @- http://URL`  as the server response is 400 Bad Request